# create all table models using indpectdb in django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a database "Employee" into SQL-Server-2016 , which contains a lot of tables such as:

```
dbo.Employee
dbo.Department
dbo.Salary
dbo.Country
dbo.Address
domain1\userId.auth_group_permissions
domain1\userId.auth_user
domain1\userId.django_session
domain1\userId.auth_permission
```

......
I have tried to generate database in tables in django models by using:

```
python manage.py inspectdb>models.py
```

but only django models generated such as AuthUserGroups, AuthUserUserPermissions, DjangoAdminLog,...
What should i have do , to generate all dbo schema tables models?

Answer (score 0):

**Give Django your database parameters**

You need to specify your database connection parameters in settings file.

Do that by editing the **DATABASES** setting and assigning values to the following keys for the '**default**' connection:

> - NAME
> - ENGINE
> - USER
> - PASSWORD
> - HOST
> - PORT

For further reference or doubts refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/